# Program file handle

Tags: c, linux, filehandle

I have a program which set the number of file handle open to unlimited at the entry point of the program. When the program runs under root, i don't have any problem with the file handle. It can open lot more than initial limit 1024. But of non-root user it is not going beyond 1024. Max file handle open i see is 1007.

The user is in the sudoer list and there is not entry for the user in the */etc/security/limit.conf*. I see for both root and the non-root user does not have entry in the limit.conf file.

Is there any other configuration I am missing? What is the hard limit for number of file handle open for a root and non-root user?

Comment: Increasing the hard limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf` solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a program which set the number of file handle open to unlimited at the entry point of the program.

If you run your program as a non-root user (and it does not have certain privileges) it cannot increase a hard limit, as pointed out in the `setrlimit` manual page:

> [...] an unprivileged process may only [...] (irreversibly) lower its hard limit.

The initial hard limits are system-specific and can be accessed by `getrlimit`.